# php ImageTTFText, Image only filled with Text if echo before

Tags: php, echo, captcha, imagettftext

Hey i got some crazy problem by making a captcha.

I creating a shuffle variable and give it to the session, then i opening the image.php

captcha.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Session start
SESSION_START();


// delet old CAPTCHA-Code from Session 
unset( $_SESSION["captcha"] );



// the Array
$text[] = "2";
$text[] = "4";
$text[] = "5";
$text[] = "7";
$text[] = "8";
$text[] = "A";
$text[] = "B";
$text[] = "C";
$text[] = "D";
$text[] = "E";
$text[] = "F";
$text[] = "G";
$text[] = "H";
$text[] = "J";
$text[] = "K";
$text[] = "M";
$text[] = "N";
$text[] = "P";
$text[] = "Q";
$text[] = "R";
$text[] = "S";
$text[] = "T";
$text[] = "U";
$text[] = "V";
$text[] = "W";
$text[] = "X";
$text[] = "Y";
$text[] = "Z";

//mixup array
shuffle ( $text );

//getting the first 5 Charakters
$outputtext = array_slice ($text, 0, 5);


//give it to the session
$_SESSION["captcha"] = implode($outputtext);
session_write_close();

echo "Captcha ist: ".$_SESSION["captcha"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

 <img src="captchaimage.php" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle;">

</html>
```

captchaimage.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


SESSION_START();

Header ("Content-type: image/png");

$str = $_SESSION["captcha"];



$bild = ImageCreateFromPNG ("http://www.php.de/images/captcha.logo1.png");


$farbe_w = ImageColorAllocate ($bild, 255, 255, 255);
$farbe_b = ImageColorAllocate ($bild, 0, 0, 0);


ImageTTFText ($bild, 32, -30, 224,  112, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf",
              $str[0]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32, -90, 288, 208, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf",
              $str[1]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,   0, 208, 336, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf",
              $str[2]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,  45,  128, 304, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf",
              $str[3]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,  99,  128, 192, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf",
              $str[4]);


header( "Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" ); 



ImagePng     ($bild);


ImageDestroy ($bild);

?>
```

this works fine, but if i delete the echo from captcha.php

this Line: `echo "Captcha ist: ".$_SESSION["captcha"];`

i get an image without characters, like the session is empty, but if the session is realy empty the image wount be createt.

Why dose the captchaimage.php only getting the correct session, if i wrote the echo line in the captcha.php?

Comment: Isn't it easier to maintain and read the code to instantiate arrays like this: `$text = array('2', '4', '5', '8', 'A', 'B', 'C', ...);`? Anyway, try to remove this line: `session_write_close();`. I have never used such call and had never problems with sessions.

Comment: i change the array like your way, same problem.
i allready tried to comment out the session write close line, same problem.
i tried some other echo variables, if i set `echo "";` or `echo " ";` the image will be created without Text, if i set `echo "1";` or `echo "test";` the image will be created correct.
iam very confused

Answer (score 2):

A small test:

Change the code a little bit - instead of calling captchaimage.php as the source of Your image, try to move Your captchaimage.php logic into the captcha.php this way:

captcha.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Session start
SESSION_START();

// delet old CAPTCHA-Code from Session 
unset( $_SESSION["captcha"] );

// the Array
$text = array("2", "4", "5", "7", "8", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", /*...*/);

//mixup array
shuffle ( $text );

//getting the first 5 Charakters
$outputtext = array_slice ($text, 0, 5);

//give it to the session
$_SESSION["captcha"] = implode($outputtext);

$bild = ImageCreateFromPNG ("http://www.php.de/images/captcha.logo1.png");

$farbe_w = ImageColorAllocate ($bild, 255, 255, 255);
$farbe_b = ImageColorAllocate ($bild, 0, 0, 0);

ImageTTFText ($bild, 32, -30, 224,  112, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf", $str[0]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32, -90, 288, 208, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf", $str[1]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,   0, 208, 336, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf", $str[2]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,  45,  128, 304, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf", $str[3]);
ImageTTFText ($bild, 32,  99,  128, 192, $farbe_w, "arial.ttf", $str[4]);

ob_start();
ImagePng     ($bild);
$image = ob_get_clean();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

 <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle;">

</html>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Wow this works fine, with safari and firefox. But not with IE 6 & 8.

Comment: IE6 sucks... Wondering that people are still using it... Strange it won't work in IE8, maybe IE lte 8 don't know the `<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" />` markup.

Comment: Ok dont think about IE6, but IE8 should work.
Is there no easy way to display it also in IE8?
I searched the web, but dont find an understandable documentation.
Is there an other way to display the $image directly in html/php?